# How can I filter a Perl DBIx recordset with 2 conditions on the same column?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I'm getting my feet wet in [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBIx::Class) — loving it so far.

One problem I am running into is that I want to query records, filtering out records that aren't in a certain date range.

It took me a while to find out how to do a `<=` type of match instead of an equality match:

```
my $start_criteria = ">= $start_date";
my $end_criteria = "<= $end_date";
my $result   = $schema->resultset('MyTable')->search(
  {
    'status_date' => \$start_criteria,
    'status_date' => \$end_criteria,
  });
```

The obvious problem with this is that since the filters are in a hash, I am overwriting the value for "status_date", and am only searching where the status_date <= $end_date.  The SQL that gets executed is:

```
SELECT me.* from MyTable me where status_date <= '9999-12-31'
```

I've searched CPAN, Google and SO and haven't been able to figure out how to apply 2 conditions to the same column.  All documentation I've been able to find shows how to filter on more than 1 column, but not 2 conditions on the same column.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Can someone here point it out to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIRC, you should be able to pass an array reference of multiple search conditions (each in its own hashref.) For example:

```
my $result = $schema->resultset('MyTable')->search(
  [ { 'status_date' => \$start_criteria },
    { 'status_date' => \$end_criteria },
  ]
);
```

**Edit:** Oops, nervermind. That does an OR, as opposed to an AND.

It looks like the right way to do it is to supply a hashref for a single `status_date`:

```
my $result = $schema->resultset('MyTable')->search(
    { status_date => { '>='  => $start_date,  '<='  => $end_date } } 
);
```

This stuff is documented in [SQL::Abstract](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SQL-Abstract/), which DBIC uses under the hood.

Comment: Perfect!  That is exactly what I needed!

If only that were documented better...

Thanks much, friedo, I apreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

There is `BETWEEN` in SQL and in DBIx::Class it's supported:

```
my $result = $schema->resultset('MyTable')
   ->search({status_date => {between => [$start_date,$end_date]}});
```